# Ethernet PHY ESD protection, difference in components

Tags: ethernet, protection, esd

I'm using a ***Würth Elektronik 7498210220A*** jack [(datasheet)](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/7498210220A.pdf) and I need to add ESD protection to TD and RD lines of this Ethernet connector (with integrated magnetics).

Application of this Ethernet adapter is industrial.

I've found these products below.

**Question:** What advantages and disadvantages do these different layouts have?

---

***Semtech RCLAMP3354S.TCT*** [(details)](https://www.semtech.com/products/circuit-protection/low-capacitance/rclamp3354s)

[image: Semtech RClamp3354S pinout]

<sub>Image source: [Semtech RClamp3354S datasheet](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/44000000MCrm/q3IJaquvh9BkANCL4E8HYT8vxS.k3jwPHRhsWr6XNsI)</sub>

---

***Semtech RCLAMP2502L.TBT*** [(details)](https://www.semtech.com/products/circuit-protection/low-capacitance/rclamp2502l)

[image: Semtech RClamp2502L pinout]

<sub>Image source: [Semtech RClamp2502L datasheet](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/E0000000JelG/a/44000000MCgt/RPacAmtWIx8cWci6_tfzWlKJG36tnuTJ3AF6zoFaMvc)</sub>

---

***Semtech RCLAMP3374N.TCT*** [(details)](https://www.semtech.com/products/circuit-protection/low-capacitance/rclamp3374n)

[image: Semtech RClamp3374N pinout]

<sub>Image source: [Semtech RClamp3374N datasheet](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/E0000000JelG/a/2R0000001TBb/1Sb_xwpUbvH6q70WnqQwnuIuQfNX7THrFXZCKGHIIn8)</sub>

---

***Littelfuse SLVU2.8-4BTG*** [(details)](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/tvs-diode-arrays/lightning-surge-protection/slvu2_8_4btg_s/slvu2_8_4btg_s.aspx)

[image: Littelfuse SLVU2.8-4BTG pinout]

<sub>Image source: [Littelfuse SLVU2.8-4BTG datasheet](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=8a8d1118-769e-4c6e-b993-a7819a40fbae&filename=littelfuse-tvs-diode-array-slvu2-8-4btg-s-datasheet)</sub>

Comment: All but the last one limit to a certain voltage wrt ground, whereas the last one only limits differential voltage between two pins, so you'd have to connect ground to 4 pins.